# Windows Update failed to check for updates with error 0x80072EFE

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-update

I am unable to Download/Install Windows update on my Windows Sever 2016 Std. Version 1607 OS Build 14393.5501

Windows Update failed to check for updates with error 0x80072EFE

Most of the Solution are related to problems with the server unable to reach the Internet or Microsoft Update Servers, but I am able to reach the Internet from the server and able to ping 8.8.8.8 and able to download standalone updates on the same machine.

[image: No Issues on DISM and SFC]

Tried Below Steps:

```
net stop wuauserv
net stop cryptSvc
net stop bits
net stop msiserver

ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 Catroot2.old

net start wuauserv
net start cryptSvc
net start bits
net start msiserver
```

Also tried to turn off the proxy settings.

`netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie`

Also Checked if any staged package,

`dism /online /get-packages /format:table`

As a last attempt I followed the [Windows Components Reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/additional-resources-for-windows-update) howto.

Answer (score 0):

0x80072EFE (WININET_E_CONNECTION_ABORTED) is a timeout.

Or to speak in microsoft "The connection with the server was closed abnormally, BITS is unable to transfer the file successfully."

It happens when BITS is broken or the file being transferred can't be written to the destination folder on the client. This error is usually caused by connection errors while checking or downloading updates. Firewall, AV, Proxy, Security-Stuff.

You should be able to narrow it further down with:

```
bitsadmin /LIST /ALLUSERS /VERBOSE
```

Search the output for 0x80072EFE. You should see a reference to an HTTP code with a specific URL. Use curl or a browser to debug the download.